# why we use -1 in javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript

why we use -1 in javascript for loop

the example code here

```js
var arr = [1,2,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10];

function squash(arr){
    var tmp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(tmp.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
        tmp.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}

console.log(squash(arr));
```

Comment: You use it for `indexOf`, not the loop. Look up the documentation on it.

Answer (score 2):

The `indexOf` function returns `-1` if the item is **not** found in the desired array.

```js
document.write([1, 2, 3].indexOf(1)+" "); //Exists
document.write([1, 2, 3].indexOf(0)); //Does not exist
```